# SharePoint change date format in access request email

Tags: sharepoint-online, formatting, sharepoint-email, date

[image]

The image shown above is a sharepoint user access request approval email we received on the 12th of July 2023. It was approved that day. But it is formatted as mm/dd/yyyy. How do we change it to dd/mm/yyyy (12/7/2023) format instead ?

Comment: What's the sites locale in regional settings set to and are they correct? /_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx

Comment: Hi @Christoffer the locale is correct. It is set to English (Australia). Time zone also correct

Comment: Hello any updates ?